# Как в Jade вставить ссылку внутрь цикла?

Tags: html5, jade, pug

Есть массив и цикл:

```
ul.skills__list

- var labelValue = [
'БЭМ/OOCSS', ... , 'Читаю blog.csssr.ru', 'Я ленивый(-ая)', 'У меня хороший английский'];

for content, index in labelValue
     li.skills__item
          input.skills__input(type='checkbox' name= 'skills'+ index id= 'skills-id'+ index)
               label.skills__label(for= 'skills-id'+ index)= content
```

Нужно текст(**blog.csssr.ru**) в элементе массива обернуть в ссылку. Возможно ли это сделать в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант убрать экранизацию вывода

Не экранированный вывод в pug != content

Вот пример на вашем коде

```
ul.skills__list

- var labelValue = ['БЭМ/OOCSS', ... , 'Читаю <a href="blog.csssr.ru">blog.csssr.ru</a>', 'Я ленивый(-ая)', 'У меня хороший английский'];

for content, index in labelValue
     li.skills__item
          input.skills__input(type='checkbox' name= 'skills'+ index id= 'skills-id'+ index)
          label.skills__label(for= 'skills-id'+ index)!= content
```